# Putting together conditionals, input casting, and math

Tags: python

I wrote the code below with a single parameter `operator`. This parameter can only contain `*` or `/` operator as argument. My question is: Is it possible to define this argument, so that the user knows he/she can only put `*` or `/` operator as argument? (The default operator is `*`)

```
def mult_or_divid(operator = "*"):
    integer1 = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
    integer2 = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
    if operator == "*":
        return(integer1 * integer2)
    elif operator == "/":
        return(integer1 / integer2)
    else:
        return("Invalid Operator")

print(mult_or_divid("/"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `typing.Literal`:

```
from typing import Literal, Union

def mult_or_divid(operator: Union[Literal["*"], Literal["/"]] = "*"):
    ...
```

With this declaration, `mypy` will produce an error if you pass an arbitrary string:

```
mult_or_divid("asdf")  # error: Argument 1 to "mult_or_divid" has incompatible type "Literal['asdf']"; expected "Union[Literal['*'], Literal['/']]"
```

Comment: Is it also possible to return "Invalid Operator"  when the operator is other than "*" or "/" ?

Comment: Your code already does that at runtime.  You can't modify the error message produced by mypy, although you can add comments to the code so that somebody who hits the mypy error will have more context on why the type is declared that way (although in this case I think the code is self-explanatory).